# MySQL query to fetch result next 7 days when comparing 2 columns timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have 2 columns in same table, I am trying to count all id's which expiry date is greater +7 days from today column time-stamp

Please take a look into my table

user_pages

```
id |        expiry         |       today         |   Flag |
1  | 2016-02-08 15:03:57   | 2016-03-24 07:17:01 |    0   |
2  | 2016-03-31 07:17:01   | 2016-03-24 07:17:01 |    1   |
```

I trying this:

```
("SELECT COUNT(id) AS aggeorders FROM user_pages 
   WHERE user_id ='$id' 
   And expiry > today + INTERVAL 7 DAY)");
```

also I need to run a cronjob to set flag = 1

```
("update user_pages 
   if expiry > today + INTERVAL 7 DAY) set flag = 1");
```

However neither of them worked. Any ideas how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

## Query #1:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS aggeorders FROM user_pages 
WHERE user_id ='$id' 
And expiry >= today + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

## Query #2:

```
update user_pages 
set flag = 1
where expiry >= today + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: it's for cronjob gonna check that, also i need to count id's as

Comment: 1- ("SELECT COUNT(id) AS aggeorders FROM user_pages WHERE user_id ='$id' And expiry > today + INTERVAL 7 DAY)");

Comment: once i count id, i will echo '<div style="font-size: 25px;font-weight: bold">' . $row['aggeorders'] .'</div>';

Comment: but the problem is while i am trying to count id's not getting desire result in example case result id=2 because expiry is > today + 7days

Comment: query #1 not return result id

Comment: the result of  query #1 as example should be id = 2

Comment: Try `expiry >= today + INTERVAL 7 DAY)` for query #1. If id = 2, count 1 should be returned. The `id` will not be displayed in the output.